# Hierarchical Query / base on table input

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-query

Account table:

```
      ID_ACC    PARENT_ACC
        76543    76543      <-edit
        18252    76543
        34456    76543
        456567   76543
        457564   65424
        45654242 6556756
```

Info table:

```
      ID     account_id  product_id
    875621     18252       98567
    875621     34456       98567
```

Product table:

```
    ACCOUNTID  PRODUCT_ID 
      456452     98567
```

Account table contain ID of accounts. But some of account(**ID_ACC**) has parent account (**Parent_acc**) - This example presents that

```
ID_ACC:   18252,
          34456,
          456567
```

has same parent_acc (76543).

Some of childs has info (info table)

(This example presents that **18252** and **34456** are connect with info table)

Next, some info.account_id contain product (Product table) (in This example - only **18252** accountid has product which has account number:**456452**.)

```
Account.id_acc=Info.account_id
Info.product_id=Product_id.product_id
```

I would like to select all accounts hierarchy:

```
76543,
18252,
34456,
456567,
456452.
```

The hardest (for me) thing is that I need to base on table (to show). If **to_show** table is filled by eg. 34456 then accounts output need to be the same like above list.

If to_show table is filled by eg. "76543,18252,34456" then same situation as above, and so on...

All what I need is to present all hierarchy regardless which of accounts (in product table or info or account) are in to_show table... As input I can get child/parent or account from product table.
I was trying to do that, but unfortanely it is too hard for me (as I'm totally newbie in hierarchy queries..).
Guys, could you help me?

```
create table account (
id_acc number,
parent_acc number
)
;
create table info
(
ID number,
Account_id number,
Product_id number
);
create table product (
Account_id number,
product_id number
);
create table to_show (
ID number
);
insert into account (id_acc,parent_acc)) values (76543,76543);
insert into account (id_acc,parent_acc) values (18252,76543);
insert into account (id_acc,parent_acc) values (34456,76543);
insert into account (id_acc,parent_acc) values (456567,76543);
insert into account (id_acc,parent_acc) values (457564,65424);
insert into account (id_acc,parent_acc) values (45654242,6556756);
insert into info values (875621,18252,98567);
insert into info values (875621,34456,null);
insert into product values (456452,98567);
insert into to_show values (34456);
```

Comment: I would love to help; but I have no idea what you're really after.  This doesn't seem to be a hierarchy to me; but a list of all accounts related to 76543.  Is that what you're really after?  all the accounts related to 76543 in some fashion even if it's though a product relationship?

Comment: I think you say "hierarchy" instead of something else. Please think of a better word for it. Otherwise, the question is clear and detailed; we just don't see what you want to achieve.

Comment: Why doesn't 45654242 appear in your results?  I see no reason in the question stated to exclude them?  Is it because it's not a child of 76543?

Comment: That's only an example of data. As input I have table to_show which will contain accounts id which I want to display (of course including all hierarchy). Maybe hierarchy is a bad word for that - all "tree" - I think it is better ; )

Comment: xQbert: 45654242 can't appear because as input I have account: 34456 . And account 34456  is no relate with 45654242

Comment: @user5506560 Yeah I completely missed the to_Show concept in my initial pass on this.  I believe the update now should address all known issues at this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach may be to first union the missing hierarchy from `product` and `info` into account and then generate the results...  Since `Product` and `info` have relevant data to the hierarchy we need to combine them.  I think this is likely the part that was the most troubling.  Not all the hierarchy data was in one place.  Once I realized that, the need for a union to allow the connect by prior to work was born.

So we join `product` to `info` to get the needed additional hierarchical data and union this to the account table.  This results in a dataset containing all the needed parent child relationships.

We can then use `connect by prior` to traverse the hierarchy.

```
SELECT a.id_acc, level as lvl
FROM (SELECT id_acc, parent_acc FROM account 
      UNION 
      SELECT P.Account_ID, i.account_id  FROM info i
      INNER JOIN product p 
       on I.Product_ID=P.Product_ID) A
START WITH A.ID_ACC=76543
CONNECT BY prior  a.id_acc=a.parent_acc
```

This would return:

```
Account Lvl
76543   1
18252   2
456452  3
34456   2
456567  2
```

Note: 456452 exists under 18252 so the relationship from the hierarchy is maintained; implying 76543 has 3 children (18252, 34456, 456567) and 18252 has a child 456452.

I think this is the best I can come up with given some assumptions about your question.

You could add some other bells and whistles to it if you need to know full path  (`sys_connect_by_path`) or if you have loops in the data you need to eliminate (`nocycle`) or isLeaf (`connect_by_isLeaf`) to show childless records in the hierarchy.

```
SELECT a.id_acc
     , level as lvl
     , SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ID_Acc, '/') "Path"
     , CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF "IsLeaf"
FROM (SELECT id_acc, parent_acc FROM account 
      UNION
      SELECT P.Account_ID, i.account_id  
      FROM info i
      INNER JOIN product p 
        on I.Product_ID=P.Product_ID) A
START WITH a.id_acc=76543
CONNECT BY nocycle prior a.id_acc=a.parent_acc
```

This would result in something like:

```
ID_acc  lvl Path                  isLeaf
76543   1   /76543                0
18252   2   /76543/18252          0
456452  3   /76543/18252/456452   1
34456   2   /76543/34456          1
456567  2   /76543/456567         1
```

For a full list of features see [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)

I kind of downplayed the importance of not having loops in the data by using `nocycle`.  Your results may be incorrect should loops in the data exist.

With a bit more work we can determine the top levels involved in to_Show though this:

```
select distinct ID_ACC
from (SELECT id_acc, parent_acc FROM account 
      UNION
      SELECT P.Account_ID, i.account_id  
      FROM info i
      inner join product p 
        on i.product_id=p.product_id) a
where parent_acc is null
connect by  prior a.parent_acc = a.id_acc
start with id_acc in (select id from to_show)
```

and combine it with the above to achieve the desired results with no hardcoding.

```
SELECT a.id_acc
     , level as lvl
     , SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ID_Acc, '/') "Path"
     , connect_by_isleaf "IsLeaf"
FROM (SELECT id_acc, parent_acc FROM account 
      UNION
      SELECT P.Account_ID, i.account_id  
      FROM info i
      INNER JOIN product p 
        on i.product_id=p.product_id) a
connect by nocycle prior a.id_acc=a.parent_acc
start with id_acc in 
(
select distinct ID_ACC
from (SELECT id_acc, parent_acc FROM account 
      UNION
      SELECT P.Account_ID, i.account_id  
      FROM info i
      inner join product p 
        on i.product_id=p.product_id) a
where parent_acc is null
connect by  prior a.parent_acc = a.id_acc
start with id_acc in (select id from to_show))
```

So all we did here was use start with in a subquery to get the top level domain of each record in to_Show, and invert the relationship so we crawled up the tree instead of down it and then used that distinct top level domain to return the entire hierarchy; thus showing the nodes in to_show; and the entire hierarchy in which it resides.

[image]

or as a CTE (Common Table Expression) for readability and refactoring to eliminate duplication.

```
with 
--Let's combine the hierarchies so they are all in one place.
hsource as (
   select id_acc, parent_acc from account 
   UNION
   SELECT P.Account_ID, i.account_id  
   FROM info i
   inner join product p 
   on i.product_id=p.product_id),
--Now lets get the top domain or root nodes of each item in To_Show
top_domain as (
   select distinct id_acc  
   from (hSource) a
   where parent_acc is null  --this null compare is actually what tells us it's a root/Top domain!  Assumption being all roots have null parent_Acc!
   connect by  prior a.parent_acc = a.id_acc
   start with id_acc in (select id from to_show))
--Now lets use those top domains or root notes to render the hierarchy of each.
SELECT a.id_acc
     , level as lvl
     , SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ID_Acc, '/') "Path"
     , connect_by_isleaf "IsLeaf"
FROM (Select id_acc, parent_acc from hSource) a
connect by nocycle prior a.id_acc=a.parent_acc
start with id_acc in  (Select ID_ACC from Top_Domain)
```

Lastly... If my assumption that the `parent_Acc` is null is incorrect then you'll need to change the query in top_domain to the below:  `Connect by prior` assumes that the top level will be null otherwise you get looping data which is why you can't simply set `a.ID_ACC=a.parent_Acc`, so we just alter two statements data using case statements to make a `Parent_ACC is null` to be a true statement.  Technically the `where` clause could just be `ID_ACC=parent_Acc`, but I wanted to keep with the theme.  The `connect by prior` line ***MUST*** be changed however.  Remember up above when I said no loops in data... Well when `ID_ACC=parent_ACC` that causes a loop.  I mean come on! how can I be my own parent?  But we handled it using case statements.

```
with 
--Let's combine the hierarchies so they are all in one place.
hsource as (
   select id_acc, parent_acc from account 
   UNION
   SELECT P.Account_ID, i.account_id  
   FROM info i
   inner join product p 
   on i.product_id=p.product_id),
--Now lets get the top domain or root nodes of each item in To_Show
top_domain as (
   select distinct a.id_acc
   from (hsource) a
--Modification starts here...
   where case when  a.parent_acc =a.id_Acc then null else a.parent_Acc end is null
   connect by prior (case when a.parent_acc=a.id_acc then null else a.parent_Acc end) = a.id_acc
--ends here
   start with a.id_acc in (select id from to_show))
--Now lets use those top domains or root notes to render the hierarchy of each.
    SELECT a.id_acc
         , level as lvl
         , SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ID_Acc, '/') "Path"
         , connect_by_isleaf "IsLeaf"
    FROM (Select id_acc, parent_acc from hSource) a
    connect by nocycle prior a.id_acc=a.parent_acc
    start with id_acc in  (Select ID_ACC from Top_Domain)
```

Comment: xQbert - thanks for reply : ) But I have to avoid hardcoding. You used a.id_acc = 76543. As I mentioned as input I will get table to_show. Data in table account,product,info were only an example to present what I want to achieve.

Comment: Let's assume that table to_show is filled by "34456" . Base on that account I need to show all hierarchy/account tree.  Output will present the same values as yours code. But like i mentioned - unfortanely I can't use hard-coding... I don't know which accounts will be in to_show table.

Comment: @user5506560 lunch... enhanced to include to_show.  I'm assuming the values in to_Show could be at any level in the hierarchy and you want us to to go to the top of each of those hierarchies and return the entire tree.

Comment: I also refactored the code to a Common Table Expression to reduce redundancy and improve readability.  Yet the results remain the same as the screenshot!

Comment: xQbert - U are the best : )It is really helpfull... : ) I have one more question - Assume that instead of null in Account table (for 76543 ID) I will have the same number 76543. So the only difference is 76543 instead of null. Still that account is a parent. How should I change the code? I was trying to change "where parent_acc is null" on where parent_acc = a.id_acc but It doesn't work.

Comment: I edited my question (data in table account). Could you take a look?

Comment: @user5506560 updated. Connect by prior assumes top domain parent is null.  Since this isn't the case... I used a case statement to make it the case! :P  Case solved.  In case you didn't get it I was trying to be humorous.  Lines starting --Modifications starts here --ends here  tell you where the change was made.